# Has anyone faced Geolocation permission alert for iOS showing twice issue along with bundle location?

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build, cordova-3.8.0

Geolocation permission alert for iOS showing twice along with bundle location .

- I have tried by installing latest plugin and other similar answers provided for this
- Even used below key in info.plist

  `"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"`
- But still I m getting below error:

  > "private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0846B1D6-02AB-4846-ACD2-F722214B9015/myapp.app/www/index.html" in iOS phone gap project.

Can any one suggest me if any other ways to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved this with on device ready function loading to body tag

```
 function onDeviceReady(){
     return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

   }


 function onLoad()
{
     if (typeof navigator.device == "undefined"){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
        onDeviceReady();
    }
 }


 <body onload="onLoad();">
```

Comment: Can you give a little more background or explanation on what your code is doing? The listener on the "backbutton" seems like a red herring ...

Comment: Actually I have method for backbutton in my project which I have used in my code.. But here backbutton is no way related to geolocation..Here to avoid alert twice, geolocation should be called after device is loaded(ondeviceReady) ..So I have called geolocation initialisation in onDeviceReady..So it is <body onload="onLoad();">